# Error running Robot framework keyword from a Python function - RobotNotRunningError('Cannot access execution context')

Tags: python, flask, robotframework

I am trying to run a Robot Framework keyword from Python function that's exposed as flask app. I was able to call this python function from another robot test suite but when run the same from Flask app - I am getting error, RobotNotRunningError('Cannot access execution context'). Would some one guide how to fix this issue, please.

Robot Framework version 5.0.1,
Python3.9

Python script:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from robot.api.deco import keyword

app = Flask(__name__)
...
@app.get('/getAcctData') 
def get_acctData():
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'
    endPoint=  request.args.get('myKeyword') or 'get_defaultAcct'
    username = request.args.get('userid') or 'TEST_USER'
    password = request.args.get('password') or 'TEST_PW'
    BuiltIn().import_resource('/Users/S123/myProject/Tests/keywordsLibrary.robot')
    return(BuiltIn().run_keyword('endPoint',username, password))
```

and the keywordsLibrary file looks like this

```
   *** Settings ***
   Library                 ${EXECDIR}/Libraries/robot_test_app.py 
   Library                 ${EXECDIR}/Libraries/basic.py 
   Library                 OperatingSystem
   Library                 RequestsLibrary
   Library                 Collections

   *** Variables ***
   ${ACCT_API_BASE_URL}=      https://acct-api-svc.saraTestOrg.com/api
   ${PAYLOADFile}=                ${EXECDIR}/TestData/acctRequests_payload.txt

   *** Keywords ***

  SaraSampleKeyword
    ${randomreturn}=    set variable    hello from Sara sample Keyword
    [return]   ${randomreturn}

  get_acct_api
  [Arguments]        ${API_ENDPOINT}   ${Client_ID}   ${Cleint_Secret}
  [Documentation]    call specific acct api end points 
   ------ some code here
```

The full stack trace
[image]

Comment: Not possible or at least very hard and would require changes into core  of robotframework itself.

Comment: Did you try Remote library interface instead? 

https://github.com/robotframework/RemoteInterface